# Apple Script application control

Tags: applescript

Thanks for reading my question. I have an issue I was hoping you could help me with. the following apple script will run but ends up timing out because the application is not selected; the icon just bounces on the mac server dock (OSX 10.85). What am I doing wrong?

```
tell application "(Application Name)"
    activate
    getURL "(Server URL)"
    delay 30
    tell database "(database name)"
        do script "(Script Name)"
        delay 60
        close
    end tell
end tell
do shell script "(Shell script path)"
```

Also, I'd like to tell the application to quit prior to running the shell script.

Any and all advice would be appreciated.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Without knowing the actual application, and/or seeing its scripting dictionary that include getURL and database, no way to help you. Included the actually shell command in you do shell script line as well.

Answer (score 0):

To quit an app, all you do is put a “quit” command inside its tell block, typically as the last command in the tell block:

```
tell application "Safari"
    quit
end tell
```

Verify that “getURL” is the right command for the app you are targeting. The modern version is “open location.”

When you run your script from AppleScript Editor, you can tap on “Event Log” at the bottom of the window and see a log of events that occurred during your script’s execution. You can often see what went wrong there.

If your AppleScript is what is timing out, you can use with timeout:

```
with timeout of 3600 seconds
-- do something within an hour
end timeout
```

As jweaks said, you need to provide more information to get real help. Every application extends AppleScript in its own way. Your script may be perfect or it may not. There is no way for someone to know without knowing what application your script runs on. It’s like asking for help with Photoshop work but not telling anyone it is Photoshop you are working in.